# autoencoders for radiographs - do watermarks affect the performance considerably

Tags: neural-networks, python, unsupervised-learning, image-processing, autoencoders

I have to implement an autoencoder to reconstruct the input radiographs and do unsupervised feature learning in the process. However, the radiographs that I have contain some watermarks like X-ray machine signatures, other letters like R (for right) and L (for left) etc.

To what extent are these watermarks/texts going to affect the performance of the autoencoder in terms of its reconstruction error and its feature learning capabilities?

Actually, there are hundreds of images available, and removing these watermarks is infeasible. Also, I tried removing the watermarks using image inpainting but it did not give satisfactory results. So I am wondering if the original images can be used as such for doing unsupervised feature learning using autoencoders. For reference, I am attaching one/two radiographs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you detect them and then mask them out?

Comment: Or data augment with text to ensure invariant to text

Comment: I have got a potential solution at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95512/how-to-automatically-remove-text-from-images where I am trying to follow the section "Part 1 - Unknown overlay text, unknown position" The developer has also shared his/her code but not sure in which language it is written (to me it looks like Python though not sure). When  I tried to copy the code, there was an error in the line - "image = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/LyJTe.png"]".  Any help.